# How to print specific part of a file?

Tags: python, file

Input File:

```
%-----------------------------------------
Task:
- [ ] Learn chapter-1
- [ ] Learn chapter-1

%-----------------------------------------
Finished Task:
- [x] Learn chapter-1

%-----------------------------------------
Upcoming Task:
- [*] Learn chapter-1
```

Expected output File:

```
%-----------------------------------------
Task:
- [ ] Learn chapter-1
- [ ] Learn chapter-1
%-----------------------------------------
```

**Code Sample**

```
data_file = open("test.txt")
block = ""
found = False

for line in data_file:
    if found:
        block += line
        if line.strip() == "Finished Task:": break
    else:
        if line.strip() == "Task":
            found = True
            block = "Task"

data_file.close()
```

**Problem** is I want to print only the text between Task including the line with %----------------. Any suggestion is greatly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: now this is a really unpractical data format for automatic processing.  are you able to change it, or is it coming from outside of your application?

Comment: yes I can change it. Actually the file structure is designed as it needed for the application. Thanks.

Comment: then you should stick to a plain CSV format which is WAY easier to process. afterwards you can design all those fancy lines and brackets  when you need to output your todo list. in the CSV file you'd have one line per task, first column is one letter - the status of a task (U/F/?). the second column is the task description. how's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with minimal modifications :

```
data_file = open("task.txt")
block = ""
found = False

for line in data_file:
    if found:
        if line.strip() == "Finished Task:": 
           break
        else:                # <--
           block += line     # <--  
    else:
        if line.strip() == "Task:":  # <-- 
            found = True
            block = line

data_file.close()
```

This code give me the output

```
Task:
- [ ] Learn chapter-1
- [ ] Learn chapter-1

%-----------------------------------------
```

Is it what you want? However, in my opinion in this case the best solution is offered by regular expression